# Channel.isWritable notofication in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I have a scenario where I need to keep writing to a `Channel`. In case it is unable to take further data  ( because of the buffers being full etc ) , I need to stop writing , but need to resume as soon as the channel becomes writable again. How do I determine this instant when a channel becomes writable again ? Is there a callback event that is fired which I can override ? I am extending `SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler` in my business handler - this has a method `channelInterestChanged()` - but not sure if this is correct hook to tap into ?

I was hoping to avoid using primitive thread-based wait mechanisms like wait-notify as these will involve context switching. Any non-blocking way to achieve this wait ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override the `channelInterestChanged()` method.

Something like that:

```
public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    ....

    @Override
    public void channelInterestChanged(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        if (e.getChannel().isWritable() {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the job

Comment: What is the newer method in netty 4.x

Comment: in netty 4.x it is "channelWritabilityChanged(...)"